# Swing - creating GridLayout using JTextfield input

Tags: java, swing, grid-layout, illegalargumentexception

I'm trying to create a `Gridlayout`. I'm using two parameters - m and n that are taken from `JTextField` components.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class GUI extends JFrame
{
public static final int HEIGHT = 75;
public static final int WIDTH = 450;

    JLabel m_label, n_label;
    JTextField m_enter,n_enter;
    JButton generate;
    int m,n;
    GUI g;

public void draw()
{
    m=Integer.parseInt(m_enter.getText());
    n=Integer.parseInt(n_enter.getText());
    new Chess();
}

GUI()
{

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT));
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setVisible(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);

    m_label = new JLabel("M:");
    m_enter = new JTextField(5);
    n_label = new JLabel("N:");
    n_enter = new JTextField(5);

    generate = new JButton("Generate!");

    add(m_label);
    add(m_enter);

    add(n_label);
    add(n_enter);

    add(generate);
    pack();

    generate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            draw();
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new GUI();
}}
```

Chess Class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class Chess extends JDialog
{
GUI g;
public static final int HEIGHT = 600;
public static final int WIDTH = 600;
int m,n;

Chess()
{
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT));
    setVisible(true);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(m,n));
    pack();
}
}
```

It creates following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: rows and cols cannot both be zero
at java.awt.GridLayout.<init>(GridLayout.java:195)
at java.awt.GridLayout.<init>(GridLayout.java:166)
at Chess.<init>(Chess.java:15)
at GUI.draw(GUI.java:23)
at GUI$1.actionPerformed(GUI.java:55)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 2) See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Comment: Please show your actual and complete error message, not an interpretation of the message. Also indicate which lines are involved.

Comment: Heck, you're not even posting the code that throws the exception! It's likely coming from your Chess code. Note that you're not passing `m` nor `n` into your Chess constructor.

Comment: *"Swing - creating GridLayout using JTextfield input"* BTW - sounds painful for the user. Offer them a `JSpinner` (or two) using a `SpinnerNumberModel` ..

Comment: Yes it is definitely coming from within the Chess code -- code you've not posted. Don't ignore the error message, but read it critically as it will show you where your problem is and what it is. Solution -- pass `m` and `n` into Chess so that Chess can use it.

Comment: OK, look at Chess -- where do you set m or n??? This isn't a programming question but a basic logic problem -- m and n won't magically change. Again give Chess a constructor, pass in m and n, and set m and n within the constructor.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels A combo. of your comments could be an answer..

Comment: @AndrewThompson: answer created, but made into a community wiki since I hate answering such questions.

Comment: Well .It seems that the only problem was the absence of these two variables in constructor. It solves my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're never setting Chess's m or n values. Give Chess a constructor that allows outside classes the ability to set these fields, and then pass them in.

```
Chess(int m, int n) {
    this.m = m;
    this.n = n;
    //if statement to check if NULL or both set to zero
    //{
        //TODO:  Check to make sure no NULLs or Zero values
    //}
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT));
    setVisible(true);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(m,n));
    pack();
}
```

Key lessons:

- There is no "magic" in programming. Your fields will not magically change, and if you want them to change, you the programmer must change them.
- Don't ignore the exception stacktrace message that you receive as it contains valuable information that will help you solve your problems, including **where** the problem is and **what it is**.
- Your question initially was non-answerable because you didn't post the key code that was causing the error (see the point above). Please have a look at the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) as well as the [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections for more information on how to improve your future questions and increase your chances of getting decent help.